# how to return to upload form with image now present?

Tags: php, redirect, upload

I have created a form that allows users to upload.  I have the "action" as "action: upload.php" and the code runs fine.

However after the upload the browser displays the output of `upload.php` as expected. What do I need to add to upload.php so it automatically returns back to the form where I can then show the image recently uploaded there also?

Answer (score 1):

USE: `header("location:yourpage.php")` in your `upload.php` to redirect to `yourpage.php` where yourpage.php may be the page where you want to show images

If you are experiencing problems on that Use:

```
ob_start();
header("location:yourpage.php")
```

That should Help